# Use of だと when not quoting

Tags: grammar, particle-と, conditionals

Is `だと` used similarly to `って` or `は` but it also largely emphasises what's has come before it so that you can commented?

This is why I get a feeling of it meaning something along the lines of `"This flavour I'd assumed it would be until now has a certain (strong) emotional touch to it."` - emphasising the fact that (unexpectedly) the flavour gives a strong emotional impression despite it being what they had assumed; please correct me if I'm wrong.

[image: だと in manga]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are multiple distinct と's other than the quoting one, each has quite important meanings. Here it is **conditional**.

> ここまで想定内の味だと、ある意味感動的よ！
> "If it is of this much unsurprising taste, it's impressive in another way!"
> = *It tastes so unamazing that almost can be called amazing!*

See also:

- [Confusion with Japanese particle と in its multiple uses](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/15363/7810)
- [と's role in 「それは触ると柔らかい」](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/41121/7810)

Comment: I see, when と is used as a conditional with nouns, is だ always needed?

Comment: @Hou0bou Yes, because it's a conjunctive connecting clauses (predicates), not nouns. だ is like English "be": "human" is not a predicate, "be human" is.